# HP LeftHand vs VMware VSA

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage-area-network, lefthand

I am trying to compare VMware's new VSA with the HP LeftHand VSA.  Both products allow you to run the SAN node as a VM.  Reading VMware's documentation I get the impression that VMs on the same host as the SAN node access data from that node at local storage speeds, while I get the impression with HP's VSA that it presents as iSCSI and thereby subject to that slow down.

I like the HP VSA because it would allow us more than 3 nodes and it allows the migration to hardware based SAN or even mixed hardware and VM based nodes, but if I am understanding the performance difference with VMware's product I would consider that a greater value and worth the 3-node limit.

My question is with HP LeftHand VSA, since you configure targeting the cluster and not the node, will it not be able to bi-pass the artificial performance ceiling of the virtualized switch and NIC in the communication chain between the local VM and local virtual SAN node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the iSCSI protocol, the Lefthand VSA will add some latency to any disk IO requests processed through it. Unless you're looking for a high performance solution, this shouldn't be noticeable compared to the latency of the storage medium however. If you're looking for some sort of high performance solution, a VSA is probably the wrong way anyhow.

Comment: Am I thinking about this in the wrong way?  iSCSI would be limited to the 1 Gb speed of the NIC where as local IO would be limited to the 6 Gb speed of the disk.  Not to mention the additional overhead of TCP.  That seems like a difference that I would expect to notice.  Am I over simplifying or missing a major point?

Comment: Local traffic doesn't actually hit the NIC. This is true of almost all networks stacks on almost all operating systems.

Comment: HP suggest using up to 8 teamed GbE NICs between a pair of servers running VSA. That will cost something, but still be cheaper than a physical SAN.

Answer (score -2):

Personal experience is that storage visualization still needs time to mature. There are speed tests on Google which show a significant overhead with storage virtualization on the VMware vSA platform. I have not seen any HP LeftHand VSA performance metrics though.

VMware does provide a while paper which goes over a few metrics, 
[Performance of VSA in VMware vSphere 5](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/techpaper/vsa-perf-vsphere5.pdf). It dipicts response time in the 1000ms range. It looks like VMware only supports a RAID-10 configuration for performance concerns.

Comment: Please read our [faq] in particular [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://serverfault.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.